# DateTime calculate fine

Tags: c#

Hi I'm wondering whats the best way to do this task!

If have three DateTimes objects named TimeOfLoan, DueDate and TimeOfReturn and if the days between TimeOfLoan and DueDate is over 15 days I want to give a fine for every day that passed before it is returned. Like first day 10 euro second day 10 euro etc.

Comment: leave the 'best way' for later... what was the 'way' you thought of??

Comment: I believe you shall come up with what you have written so far just a rough algo or something

Answer (score 2):

If you subtract one date from another, you set a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx). From that you can use the `Days` property to get the number of days.

```
numberOfDays = (myDateTime1.Date - myDateTime2.Date).Days;
```

Comment: This failes in a number of situations. 
Trace.WriteLine((DateTime.Parse("3/10/2000 9:00 PM") - DateTime.Parse("3/11/2000 2:00 AM")).Days);

He likely wants that to return 1 and not 0

Answer (score 1):

and try this it shall work i believe with little tweaking maybe

```
DateTime d1;
DateTime d2;
string result = (d1 - d2).TotalDays.Tostring();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are looking for, but this is the idea:

`DateTime TimeOfLoan = new DateTime(2012,1,1);

DateTime DueDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 18);

int days = DueDate.Subtract(TimeOfLoan).Days;

int finePrice = 10;

Console.WriteLine("You have a fine of {0} euros!",days*finePrice);`

This will print "You have a fine of 170 euros!"